# How to check when a comment is marked as done in Word Online? Javascript API for Word Add-In

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins

I'm trying to manipulate a Word Online documents' comments with an Add-In, and to do that I'm using the `getOoxml()` function to directly read/modify the xml.

However I noticed that even though I can access the comments and its contents through the given XML, I can't seem to find a tag/attribute that tells me whether the comment has been marked as done or not.

Even though my target platform is Word Online, I unzipped a local Word document(.docx) to see what it does behind-the-scenes, and realized that Word has a separate document for the "done" property called "commentsExtended.xml". This is distinct from the "comments.xml" where the comments are stored.

This is the Add-In code I use to do a simple search in the XML returned as a string by `getOoxml()` :

```
Word.run(function (context) {

    var properties = context.document.body.getOoxml();

    return context.sync().then(function () {

        let xmlString = properties.value;

        let searchPositions = [];
        let curIndex = 0;
        let startIndex = 0;

        while((curIndex = xmlString.indexOf("done", startIndex)) > -1) {
            searchPositions.push(curIndex);
            startIndex = curIndex + 1;
        }

        console.log(searchPositions);
    });
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

This is the content stored in "commentsExtended.xml" that I can't seem to find in `getOoxml()`'s return value:

```
<w15:commentsEx mc:Ignorable="w15" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml">
  <w15:commentEx w15:done="1" w15:paraId="1930ECCA" />
  <w15:commentEx w15:done="0" w15:paraId="0B31B8E3" />
</w15:commentsEx>
```

The XML returned by `getOoxml()` in Word Online doesn't seem to include this information. Is there a way to obtain this information about a comment's "done" state within a Word Add-In?

Edit: My target version is 2016.

Comment: Given you target Word Online, does that mean this is possible for Word "offline"?